# Formatear respuesta de documento de Mongo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Parece una pregunta larga, pero en realidad muestro varios ejemplos que me suceden para explicarlo de la mejor manera posible.

Tengo un modelo de carrito como este (omito varios campos ya que no son importantes para la pregunta):

```
let carritoSchema = new Schema({
    productos: [{
        _id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Producto',
            required: [true, '{PATH} requerido']
        },
        cantidad: {
            type: Number,
            required: [true, '{PATH} requerido'],
            default: 1
        },
        precioVenta: {
            type: Number
        }
    }],
    ...
});
```

Lo que quiero es devolver un carrito (o varios) y que el formato de este sea el sigueinte:

```
"carrito": {
        "_id": "5fa436a7cd126a3548d3a877",
        "productos": [
            {
                "_id": "5fa401a1c397674458a9e945",
                "nombre": "Gin prueba",
                "codigo": "GIN1000TAN",
                "precioVenta": 580,
                "cantidad": 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

En Mongo el carrito se guarda de la siguiente forma:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fa1c542b095fc389cbc2582"),
    "productos" : [ 
        {
            "cantidad" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fa1c50cb095fc389cbc257d"),
            "precioVenta" : 60
        }, 
        {
            "cantidad" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fa1c532b095fc389cbc257f"),
            "precioVenta" : 80
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Y estoy realizando esta función para tratar de devolver el carrito como quiero:

```
let getCarritoById = (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Carrito.findById(id, '_id productos ')
        .lean()
        .populate([{
            path: 'productos._id',
            model: 'Producto',
            select: 'codigo nombre precioVenta'
        }])
        .exec((err, carrito) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: 'ServerError'
                })
            }
            if (!carrito) {
                res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: 'CarritoNotFound'
                })
            }
            
            res.json({
                ok: true,
                carrito
            })
        });
}
```

Y acá explico el problema que tengo y que quiero realizar con ese código. El primer problema, es que si hago eso la respuesta tiene este formato:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "carrito": {
        "_id": "5fa436a7cd126a3548d3a877",
        "productos": [
            {
                "cantidad": 1,
                "_id": {
                    "_id": "5fa401a1c397674458a9e945",
                    "codigo": "GIN1000TAN",
                    "nombre": "Gin 1L.",
                    "precioVenta": 590
                },
                "precioVenta": 580
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Entonces trate de mejorar la función realizando esto luego de cerrar el `if (!carrito) { ... }` :

```
carrito.productos.forEach(productoComprado => {
                let productoCarrito = {
                    _id: productoComprado._id._id,
                    codigo: productoComprado._id.codigo,
                    nombre: productoComprado._id.nombre,
                    precioVenta: productoComprado.precioVenta,
                    categoria: productoComprado._id.categoria,
                    marca: productoComprado._id.marca,
                    cantidad: productoComprado.cantidad
                }
                carrito.productos.push(productoCarrito);
                let indexProducto = carrito.productos.indexOf(productoComprado);
                if (indexProducto > -1)
                    carrito.productos.splice(indexProducto, 1);
            });
```

Esto me devuelve algo mejor formateado, el problema es que solo lo hace bien si hay un único producto dentro del array, si hay mas ya no lo hace.

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "carrito": {
        "_id": "5fa436a7cd126a3548d3a877",
        "productos": [
            {
                "_id": "5fa401a1c397674458a9e945",
                "codigo": "GIN1000TAN",
                "nombre": "Gin 1L.",
                "precioVenta": 580,
                "cantidad": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Estoy casi seguro que es problema porque como `findById` es asíncrono, todavía no esta finalizando. Alguna otra manera de intentar resolver este problema? Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la intención es mutar (*modificar*) los valores en el arreglo de productos, nada mejor que [`array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map).

Ejemplo:

```
carrito.productos = carrito.productos.map(productoComprado => {
  return {
    _id: productoComprado._id._id,
    codigo: productoComprado._id.codigo,
    nombre: productoComprado._id.nombre,
    precioVenta: productoComprado.precioVenta,
    categoria: productoComprado._id.categoria,
    marca: productoComprado._id.marca,
    cantidad: productoComprado.cantidad
  }
});
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Te consulto, si quisiera hacer el mismo formateo pero en vez de hacer una busqueda por id que me devuelve un solo carrito, hago un get y me devuelve muchos carritos cada uno con su  array de productos, como se podría realizar eso?

Comment: Podes hacerlo recorriendo cada carro y luego cada producto. Ejemplo: `carritos.map((carro) => { carro.productos = carro.productos.map(product => funcFormateadora); return carro;})`